# Live555MediaServer restarts the stream at every new connection. Why setting "reuseSource" to true is not working as expected?

Tags: c++, rtsp, live555

Live555MediaServer can be used to stream video files as rtsp streams. I have 2 clients (vlc) that connect to the server, A and B. I want to see the exact video stream in both the clients. Here is the problem: I connect A and after 10 seconds I connect B. When B is connected the video that I see starts over from the beginning, while A keeps streaming as it was.

I would like the 2 concurrent streams to be synchronized.

The live555 doc says that setting reuseFirstSource to True should work. So I tried to set reuseSource to true at DynamicRTSSPServer:121 but it didn't work. When I connect to the server using client B the video restarts from the beginning.

Boolean const reuseSource = True;

I expect to see the 2 concurrent streams synchronized even if one starts with a delay with respect to the other one.

Comment: After some digging I found out that the problem is not related to the reuseSource boolean. The calls diagram for live555MediaServer with a h264 stream is the following:  

DynamicRTSPServer -> H264VideoFileServerMediaSubsession -> FileServerMediaSubsession -> OnDemandServerMediaSubsession  

At line 113 there is this check:  
`if (fLastStreamToken != NULL && fReuseFirstSource)`  
which fails on the first check. 
For some reason fLastStreamToken is always reinitialized and thus this check fails.  
Now the question is how can I keep fLastStreamToken in between 2 rtsp clients requests?

Comment: Useful tips for debugging live555:  
- ./genMakefiles linux-gdb where the following gdb is required;
- modify the live/config.linux-gdb file, add -DDEBUG in the COMPILE_OPTS line, so that the debug in the source code is valid;
- ./genMakefiles linux-gdb . 
- make compiled file
- run gdb live555ProxyServer
- set args input parameters, such as set args -v rtsp://192.168.xxx.xxx
- you can first set a breakpoint, such as break xx, then run;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround and why there was this 'bug'.

Quick answer: set if condition at line 67 to false, i.e.
`if (smsExists && isFirstLookupInSession) {`
becomes
`if (false) {`

Explaination: Every time a new session is starting, the `isFirstLookupInSession` variable is set to `true` and the session is removed and recreated.

I wrote to the support of live555 and Finlayson told me and I quote

> “LIVE555 Media Server” code was always intended to work this way, and was intended to be a ‘stand-alone appliance’ that does not have its code modified (e.g., by changing the value of “reuseFirstSource”).

Thus the only solution for creating a RTSP server through Live555 is to create your own server starting from the testProgs examples. 
The workaround proposed here could generate unwanted behaviors, but for a simple rtsp server with multiple streams it's fine.